# Multiline Textbox Regular Expression Validator

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have this regular expression at the moment which works fine for a single input in a single line textbox:

```
ValidationExpression="[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{5}"
```

I want the same validation but for a multiline textbox which has 1 of the regex format on each line.

eg. Pass

```
AB12345
CD67890
EF12345
```

eg. Fail

```
AB12345 EF12345
CD67890
```

Tried the majority of examples given in other questions but nothing seems to work.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You could split the values into an array with

```
List<string> myValues = inputString.Split(Environment.NewLine);

foreach(string row in myValues)
 // do validation
```

This way you still validate each row by itself and can return the incorrect rows for the user to fix as well.

You could also do this inside a custom validation attribute that you decorate your model property with.
[Custom validation attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc668224%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: This is great but i cannot use this. I can only modify the expressions so I would need an expression that can do this :(

Answer (score 0):

**This Might Help you for your Requirment:**

```
         String subjectString = "A12345 EF12345 C67890 AB12345 CD67890";
        string[] ssize = subjectString.Split(null);
        try
        {

            for (int i = 0; i <= ssize.Length; i++)
            {
                Regex regexObj = new Regex("[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{5}", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                Match matchResults = regexObj.Match(ssize[i]);
                if (matchResults.Success)
                {
                    label.Text += " ";
                    label.Text += matchResults.Value.ToString();
                }
            }

        }
```